# javascript dropdown - cannot add link

Tags: javascript

I have created a basic dropdown which changes the image. I am trying to make each image to link to a desired link and change the text in the adjacent table cell but I am struggling to do it. Here is the example code.

```
    <img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif" width="300"  border="0" usemap="#Map" longdesc="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif">
    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="8,11,127,88" href="http://www.scranet.org/" target="_blank" alt="SC&amp;RA">
    </map>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
        ImgPath='http://www.vicsjavascripts.org.uk/StdImages/'; 
        ImgPreloadAry=new Array('One.gif','Two.gif','Three.gif','Four.gif'); 
        SRCAry=new Array(); 

        for (i=0;i<ImgPreloadAry.length;i++){ 
            SRCAry[i]=new Image(); 
            SRCAry[i].src=ImgPath+ImgPreloadAry[i]; 
        } 

        function Cng(sel){ 
            document.getElementById('img').src=ImgPath+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
            document.getElementById('tbl').style.backgroundImage='url('+(ImgPath+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)+')'; 
        } 
        //--> 
    </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="149"><img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif" alt="" width="130" height="80" id=img></td>
            <td width="151">Related text goes here - along with link to pdf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <table width="149" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="149" align="left" valign="top">
                    <select name="Sel" size="1" onchange="Cng(this);" >
                        <option value="One.gif">Company 1</option>
                        <option value="Two.gif">Company 2</option>
                        <option value="Three.gif">Company 3</option>
                        <option value="Four.gif">Company 4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <p>
```

Comment: Is some of you code missing at the top?  I don't see the beginning of the `<head>` tag or (I'm guessing) the start of a `<![CDATA[` section.  Also, `<img>` and `<map>` tags are not valid children of the `<head>` tag, so that could potentially cause some issues.

Comment: I appreciate the header code - I frogot to mention that I use a custom CMS which includes this automatically. If you copy and paste the code into dreamweaver you will see it works fine. I just cant get it functioning how I want it.

Answer (score 1):

Things I see wrong:

1. function Cng is never called
2. function Cng uses getElementById on "img", which has a corresponding id in the DOM, but is not in quotes and so probably won't work and "tbl" which I see no id for in your DOM. ids are unique per page so using identifiers that are going to be unique is much better for ids.